# How to apply stylesheet to view page

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, stylesheet

I am new with CSS/stylesheets. How can I apply the stylesheet I created under the vendors folder to my users show page? It's for the profile thumbnail photos.

show.html.erb:

```
<div class="parent-container">
    <% @user.photos.each do |photo| %>
        <%= link_to image_tag(photo.image_url(:thumb)), photo.image_url%>
<% end %></div></p>
```

Comment: Do you have //= require vendors/whateverfilename in your application.css

Comment: Just added it to the application.css file. Should there be something I need to add to the show.html with the code above?

Answer (score 1):

The rails asset pipeline is broken up into 3 different sections.

- app/assets is for assets that are owned by the application, usually scripted by yourself.
- lib/assets is for your own libraries' code that doesn't really fit
  into the scope of the application or those libraries which are shared
  across applications.
- vendor/assets is for assets that are 3rd party, such as js plugins and frameworks.

It is generally bad practise to start adding assets in the public folder. When your asset pipeline tries to compile and compress them in production, it won't be able to find them because it only looks in the app, lib and vendor folders.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :application %>
```

This will automatically look in the app/assets folder, and retrieve, the file named 'application'. Thereby rendering new styles within your application!

To include new stylesheets into your application, just require the file into the application file, e.g.

```
/* ...
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*= require custom_stylesheet_name
*/
```

The require will automatically look in the above mentioned folders (app/lib/vendor).

If you need further help with assets, check out the RailsGuides; they have alot of helpful and in depth content.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

## **UPDATE FOR COMMENTS:**

You can set up controller specific assets by using the `params[:controller]` value. For example, if you have a store_controller.rb you can include a store.css file. There are three 3 steps to the solution:

1. You need to remove the `*= require_tree .` from the application.css otherwise the controller specific css file will be included twice.
2. Make sure the asset pipeline precompiler is notified of the new file - all files apart from application.css are ignored unless otherwise specified. You can do this in the production.rb file with the following: `config.assets.precompile << "*.css"`.
3. Finally, you need to include controller specific file:

   ```
   <%# this would now only load application.css, not the whole tree %>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag :application, :media => "all" %>

   <%# and this would load the controller specific file %>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>
   ```

**On the other hand**, having specific stylesheets may not be best practise. Having more than one file will incur multiple server calls, reduce response times and create a load order tangle of styles. Besides the asset pipeline is designed to serve a single stylesheet which the client can cache.

Another approach may be to have a bespoke global class for each controller, i.e.

```
body.controller-users {
   background-color:#000000;
}

<body class="controller-<%= params[:controller] %>">
   #...
```

Comment: I understand the pipeline. What I was trying to ask was if there would be additional code required that I have to write in the show or the controller so that my app knows where to have this new CSS take affect. I have hover effects for the thumbnail images. I feel that I should be specifying on the users show page to start the CSS for the thumbnail section only. Thank you for the information though.

Comment: Updated my answer with more information. Upvote or tick if you find it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Assets are pulled across all HTML files from the layouts/application.html.erb

This document contains all the `<head>` & `<body>` attributes. You should see the below in there:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

This will keep all css shown in your assets in all the html files. Make sure you save files as `index.html.erb`

Here some reading to do:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Enjoy.